# Mysql fetch data per month from three tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables, which have the data from 2006 to 2017,

I want to fetch the data from tables per month, like i have users, contest and films table,

I want to fetch the data users signed up every month and and what was teh contest running that month and how many sbmission come for that contest

**I have tried**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.user_regdate, "%Y-%m") AS "_Month", COUNT(*)
FROM users as t
GROUP BY _Month,   
SELECT  COUNT(*) as films , (select c.name from contest as c where c.contest_id =f.contestid) as contest
FROM film as f GROUP BY contestid
```

but not working for me.

**Users Table**

```
----------------------------------
|user_id | user_regdate| username| 
----------------------------------
|5135    | 1164697208  | test    |  
----------------------------------
```

**Film Table**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|film_id |     date_created   | title| contestid |  User_id |
----------------------------------
|5135    | 2017-09-23 00:45:26| test |    1     |   5135    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Contest Table**

```
 --------------------------
    |contest_id |    name   | 
    --------------------------
    |5135    | First Contest| 
    --------------------------
```

### I want

### 2006-12 |-count(users) |name of contest of that month|filmsSubmitted contest |

Comment: For query related questions, you have to post the table definition, a sample data set and a sample output.

Comment: share your table structure.

Comment: @Nic3500 i have updated  the answer.

Comment: @addy  i have updated the answer

Comment: is there any relation between users table and Film Table you not define here.

Comment: @addy Yes, User_id

Comment: but where you define user_id in films structure.

Comment: @addy i have added,

Comment: I can not move to chat

Comment: ok this is how this works.  You post a **complete** question, show what you have tried, why it does not work, and what you need.  We are not supposed to be digging trying to get the info, this is not a gameshow.

Comment: @Nic3500 Please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
#For per month registered user count

select DATE_FORMAT(t.user_regdate, "%Y-%m") AS '_Month', COUNT(*) from users  group by DATE_FORMAT(t.user_regdate, "%Y-%m");

# per contest film count not used month there 
SELECT  contestid,COUNT(*) as films , (select c.name from contest as c where c.contest_id =f.contestid) as contest
FROM film as f GROUP BY contestid;

# per contest film count with month 

SELECT  contestid,COUNT(*) as films ,DATE_FORMAT(t.date_created, "%Y-%m") AS '_Month', (select c.name from contest as c where c.contest_id =f.contestid) as contest
FROM film as f GROUP BY contestid,DATE_FORMAT(t.date_created, "%Y-%m");

# per User film count total

SELECT  user_id,COUNT(*) as films , (select c.username from user_id as c where c.user_id =f.user_id) as UserName
FROM film as f GROUP BY user_id;

# per User film count in month

SELECT  user_id,COUNT(*) as films,DATE_FORMAT(t.date_created, "%Y-%m") AS '_Month' , (select c.username from user_id as c where c.user_id =f.user_id) as UserName
FROM film as f GROUP BY user_id,DATE_FORMAT(t.date_created, "%Y-%m");
```

Maybe these queries help you...

Comment: I am looking for something in one query.

Comment: explain what you want?

Comment: By modifying a little  i used the following 
 SELECT contestid,DATE_FORMAT(f.date_created, "%Y-%m") AS '_Month', (select COUNT(*) from users as t group by contestid) users, COUNT(*) as films,(select c.name from contest as c where c.contest_id =f.contestid) as contest FROM film as f GROUP BY _Month

Comment: `SELECT  contestid,DATE_FORMAT(f.date_created, "%Y-%m") AS '_Month',
(select COUNT(*) from users where DATE_FORMAT(users.user_regdate, "%Y-%m") = DATE_FORMAT(f.date_created, "%Y-%m")) Users,
COUNT(*) as films,(select c.name from contest as c where c.contest_id =f.contestid) as contest
FROM film as f GROUP BY contestid,DATE_FORMAT(f.date_created, "%Y-%m");` check once